# Using usetState in ReactJs with different values

Tags: reactjs

This is an extension to my previous post: [Using useState React hooks and calling other functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277574/using-usestate-react-hooks-and-calling-other-functions/)

In my code, I have several fields like firstName, lastName, age, gender, city, state, country, etc. So the approach which I am following now is lithe this:

```
function MyApp() {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState("");
    const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState("");
    const [city, setCity] = React.useState("");
    const [gender, setGender] = React.useState("");
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState(10);
    const [completion, setCompletion] = useState(0);
    
    calculateProgress = (firstName, lastName, city, gender, age) => {
        let total = 0;
        if(firstName.length >0 ) total += 50;
        if(lastName.length >0 ) total += 50;
        if(city.length >0 ) total += 50;
        if(gender.length >0 ) total += 50;
        if(age >0 ) total += 50;
        
        setCompletion(total);
    }

    return {
        <div>
            <input id="firstName" onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value); calculateProgress(e.target.value, lastName, city, gender, age);}
            <input id="lastName" onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value); calculateProgress(firstName, e.target.value, city, gender, age);}
            <input id="city" onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value); calculateProgress(firstName, lastName, e.target.value, gender, age);}
            <input id="gender" onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value); calculateProgress(firstName, lastName, city, e.target.value, age);}
            <input id="age" onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value); calculateProgress(firstName, lastName, city, gender, e.target.value);}
        </div>
    }
}
```

I want to optimize this code, I have declared so many variables like firstName, lastName, gender and also I have to pass multiple values for each calculateProgress function call. What is the correct way to avoid this.

Comment: Pass a single object with properties instead of a bunch of individual arguments where order matters and it's easy to screw up.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a single object with properties instead of a bunch of individual arguments where order matters and it's easy to screw up.

It would better to call `calculateProgress` in an `useEffect` so it's referencing the updated state, then you won't need to pass any arguments to it at all.

```
function MyApp() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState("");
  const [city, setCity] = React.useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = React.useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(10);
  const [completion, setCompletion] = useState(0);
    
  calculateProgress = () => {
    let total = 0;
    if (firstName.length) total += 50;
    if (lastName.length) total += 50;
    if (city.length) total += 50;
    if (gender.length) total += 50;
    if (age > 0) total += 50;
        
    setCompletion(total);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateProgress();
  }, [firstName, lastName, city, gender, age]); 

  return {
    <div>
      <input id="firstName" onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
      <input id="lastName" onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} />
      <input id="city" onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)} />
      <input id="gender" onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)} />
      <input id="age" onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, this is what I would do. The example code is missing `()` after `calculateProgress`.  Also, I wonder whether the function should be inlined into the effect?

Comment: @edemaine I was cleaning up syntax, but good catch. Regarding inlining, I believe it is more clear/correct to call `calculateProgress` from hook's callback function for 2 reasons, (1) if `calculateProgress` returns a value it would likely incorrectly be interpreted as an `useEffect` hook cleanup function, and (2) if later a cleanup function *did* need to be added it's a simple insertion and the line with `calculateProgress` remains untouched in the git blame.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily *the* correct way, but one way to avoid creating so many variables is to use a single object in state instead. Map over an array of properties when creating the inputs.

```
const properties = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'city', 'gender', 'age'];
function MyApp() {

    const [formValues, setFormValues] = React.useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        city: '',
        gender: '',
        age: 10,
    });
    const [completion, setCompletion] = useState(0);
    calculateProgress = ({ firstName, lastName, city, gender, age }) => {
        let total = 0;
        if (firstName.length > 0) total += 50;
        if (lastName.length > 0) total += 50;
        if (city.length > 0) total += 50;
        if (gender.length > 0) total += 50;
        if (age > 0) total += 50;

        setCompletion(total);
    }
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        const newValues = { ...formValues, [e.target.id]: e.target.value };
        setFormValues(newValues);
        calculateProgress(newValues);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {
                properties.map(prop => (
                    <input id={prop} onChange={changeHandler} />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks simple, what if Gender is a dropdown with limited values, also I have other fields which are select boxes and radio buttons. Is there a simple way for them also to use with properties.map as you suggested here

Comment: I don't think so. If they don't all have the same JSX, those that aren't a simple `<input>` will have to be written out. If the inputs aren't contiguous, you'll probably have to give up on the `properties.map` too.